# What does this warning means?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I have been working on Spring MVC project with Maven. When I added WEB-INF folder under "webapp" folder, the console is giving a warning which says:

```
WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.properties] to the cache for web application [/PreFix-Solution] because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
```

There are other Warnings as well with different paths, like `[/WEB-INF/classes/com/solutionsPrefix/entity/]` and  `[/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryBuilderFactory]`. Despite all these Warnings, my application is working fine. I have cleared cache from the web browser. Still, my application is working fine. Can anyone explain what are these warnings all about?

My project directories look something like this:

[image: My project directories looks some this like]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Warnings simply means, it will not stop the server it is just warning you that these warnings could lead to problems in future.

Comment: What are the solutions for those warnings?

Comment: For your cache warning you can increase cache size in config/context.xml

  <Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="500000" />

Comment: I don't have context.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase cache size  go to config/context.xml  and do the amendments

```
<Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="500000" />
```

Comment: I do not have context.xml file in my maven project.

Comment: Not in your maven project , in your tomcat/config/context.xml